# Debugging a dll in c#

Tags: c#

While searching for debugging c# DLLs, I came across this article.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c91k1xcf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx which says

You can start debugging DLL from:

The project used to create the executable that calls the DLL.
or
The project used to create the DLL itself.

I have source code(C#) for the executable project as well as the DLL.

My DLL project is in a different solution.

I want to debug the DLL from my exe project. How do I proceed with this. I have searched goole but without any detailed steps. I also added the DLL project to the exe project solution and added the break points in the source code for library project. But the breakpoint is never hit. How does the debugger know that I have loaded the source code for the DLL.  Am I missing anything?

---

*Update:*
Following Avitus and Mick's suggestions, I added the DLL project to the exe solution. Also added the reference to the DLL project and the breakpoints were hit.

I also tried to debug it through the DLL project by

project--properties--Debug and setting the exe in the Start external program. In this case the break points were not hit, it kept saying the debug symbols not loaded. I tried all the options here without any success
Configuration was set to Active(Debug).
Debug Info was set to full.
In Tools--options--debugging(Enable just my code[Managed code] was unchecked)
In Tools--options--debugging--symbols, I had all modules,unless excluded selected and the Specify excluded modules list of empty. For some reason this method did not work.

Comment: can't you just have both projects under the same solution and then reference your dll project from your exe project?

Comment: Or set the debug target of the dll to be the executable.

Comment: @Avitus..I don't want to change any code for debugging.

Comment: @Ritch....I have tried that option but still the breakpoint is not hit.

Comment: @Talk2Me for Ritch's solution, make sure the .pdb file is in the same location as the dll that's being used at run time

Answer (score 0):

The DLL has to have a debug database, or basically you have to include the DLL's solution in the solution you would debug it in.

Also visual studio has a Create Test feature which generates a bunch of test for methods and functions.

Comment: I have added my DLL's project in to my solution. But my question is how does visual studio know that it has to point to the actual code and not the DLL methods.

Comment: @Talk2Me you should make sure your .exe project uses a project reference (when you add the reference, add it from the "Projects" tab)

Comment: @Mick...Thanks you so much that worked. That saved a lot of time.